# Serverless AWS ApiGateway methodresponse

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-serverless

I've a question about Serverless and API Gateway

I have a function in my serverless.yml like this :

```
getAccount:
handler: functions/account/handlers.getAccount
events:
  - http:
      path: account
      method: get
      cors: true
      authorizer: authorize
```

But i need to add something by the API Gateway interface : 
[API Gateway expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ThV.png)

I want to add this directly in my serverless file with something like that

```
getAccount:
handler: functions/account/handlers.getAccount
events:
  - http:
      path: account
      method: get
      cors: true
      authorizer: authorize
methodresponse:
      code : 200
      header : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      body :
            content-type : "application/json"
            model : Empty
```

Does someone can tell me the syntax for serverless.yml to add this in my file ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please find below `Serverless` Sample code for `Method Responses`. 
Please let me know how you go.

```
    getAccount:
    handler: functions/account/handlers.getAccount
    events:
      - http:
          path: account
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: authorize         
          methodResponses:
            -
              statusCode: "200"
              responseBody:
                description: "Response body description"
              responseHeaders:
                -
                  name: "x-superheader"
                  description: "this is a super header"
              responseModels:
                "application/json": "CreateResponse"
            -
              statusCode: "400"
              responseModels:
                "application/json": "ErrorResponse"
```